# How to solve the InstaPy erorr while execute quickstart.py?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bots, instagram, instapy

Help me please, i'm trying to make an instagram bot using a vps (ubuntu), and this error occur when i execute the quickstart.py:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9p6e.jpg)

i cover the username.
also this is my quickstart file:

[quickstart file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKQTB.jpg)

I tried to update,upgrade the system apt-get update(upgrade), also the selenium and the geckodriver, but still don't work.